# Making a game using libgdx and when running the program immediately closes

Tags: java, libgdx

When I run the program the window immediately closes and gives some errors.

GameMapImpl.java :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTile;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.mygdx.game.entities.Entity;
import com.mygdx.game.entities.Player;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameMapImpl extends GameMap {

protected ArrayList<Entity> entities;




TiledMap tiledMap;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

public GameMapImpl() {
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    entities.add(new Player(40,300,this));



}
@Override
public void render(OrthographicCamera camera, SpriteBatch batch) {
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.end();
    super.render(camera,batch);
    for(Entity entity : entities){
        entity.render(batch);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(OrthographicCamera camera) {

}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
    for(Entity entity:entities){
        entity.update(delta,-9.8f);
    }
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
tiledMap.dispose();
}

@Override
public TileType getTileTypeByCoordinate (int layer, int col, int row) {
    TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = ((TiledMapTileLayer) tiledMap.getLayers().get(layer)).getCell(col, row);

    if (cell != null) {
        TiledMapTile tile = cell.getTile();

        if (tile != null) {
            int id = tile.getId();
            return TileType.getTileTypeById(id);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return ((TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get(0)).getWidth();
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
    return ((TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get(0)).getHeight();
}

@Override
public int getLayers() {
    return tiledMap.getLayers().getCount();
}
}
```

GameMap.java:

```
package com.mygdx.game.world;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

import static com.mygdx.game.world.TileType.TILE_SIZE;

public abstract class GameMap {

public  void render(OrthographicCamera camera, SpriteBatch batch){

}

public abstract void render(OrthographicCamera camera);

public  void update(float delta){

}

    public abstract void dispose();

/**
 * gets a tile by pixel position within the game world at a specific layer
 * @param layer
 * @param y
 * @param x
 * @return
 */
    public TileType getTileTypeByLocation(int layer, float y, float x){
        return this.getTileTypeByCoordinate(layer,(int)(x/ TILE_SIZE),(int)(y/ TILE_SIZE));
    }

/**
 * gets a tile at its coords wwithin the map at a specific layer
 * @param layer
 * @param col
 * @param row
 * @return
 */
    public abstract  TileType getTileTypeByCoordinate(int layer, int col,int row);

    public boolean doesRectCollideWithMap(float x,float y, int width, int height){
        if(x<0|| y<0|| x+width >getPixelWidth()|| y+height>getPixelHeight())
             return true;

        for (int row = (int) (y / TileType.TILE_SIZE); row < Math.ceil((y + height) / TileType.TILE_SIZE); row++) {
            for (int col = (int) (x / TileType.TILE_SIZE); col < Math.ceil((x + width) / TileType.TILE_SIZE); col++) {
                for (int layer = 0; layer < getLayers(); layer++) {
                    TileType type = getTileTypeByCoordinate(layer, col, row);
                    if (type != null && type.isCollidable()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    public abstract int getWidth();
    public abstract int getHeight();
    public abstract int getLayers();

    public int getPixelWidth(){
        return this.getWidth()* TILE_SIZE;
    }
     public int getPixelHeight(){
        return this.getHeight()* TILE_SIZE;
    }


}
```

Entity.java :

```
package com.mygdx.game.entities;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.mygdx.game.world.GameMap;

public abstract class Entity {

protected Vector2 pos;
protected EntityType type;
protected  float velocityY=0;
protected GameMap map;
protected boolean grounded=false;

public Entity(float x, float y, EntityType type, GameMap map) {
    this.pos = new Vector2(x,y);
    this.type=type;
    this.map=map;


}
public void update(float deltaTime,float gravity){
    float newY=pos.y;
    this.velocityY+=gravity*deltaTime*getWeight();
    newY +=this.velocityY*deltaTime;

    if(map.doesRectCollideWithMap(pos.x,newY,getWidth(),getHeight())){
        if (velocityY<0){
            this.pos.y=(float) Math.floor(pos.y);
            grounded=true;
        }
        this.velocityY=0;
    }else{
    this.pos.y= newY;
    grounded=false;
    }
}
public abstract void render(SpriteBatch batch);
protected void moveX (float amount){
    float newX= this.pos.x+amount;
    if (!map.doesRectCollideWithMap(newX,pos.y,getWidth(),getHeight()))
        this.pos.x=newX;
}
public Vector2 getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public EntityType getType() {
    return type;
}

public float getX(){
    return pos.x;
}

public float getY(){
    return pos.y;
}

public GameMap getMap() {
    return map;
}

public boolean isGrounded() {
    return grounded;
}

public int getWidth(){
    return type.getWidth();
}

public int getHeight(){
    return type.getHeight();
}
public float getWeight(){
    return type.getWeight();
}
}
```

Player.java:

```
package com.mygdx.game.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.mygdx.game.world.GameMap;

public class Player extends Entity {

private  static final int SPEED=80;
private static final  int JUMP_VELOCITY=5;

Texture image;

public Player(float x, float y, GameMap map) {
    super(x, y, EntityType.PLAYER, map);
    image =  new Texture("PlayerCharacter.png.png");
}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime, float gravity) {
   if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)&& grounded)
   this.velocityY +=JUMP_VELOCITY*getWeight();
    super.update(deltaTime, gravity);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
        moveX(-SPEED*deltaTime);
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
        moveX(SPEED*deltaTime);
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {

    batch.draw(image,pos.x,pos.y,getWidth(),getHeight());
}
}
```

MyGdxGame.java:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.mygdx.game.world.GameMap;
import com.mygdx.game.world.GameMapImpl;



public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

OrthographicCamera cam;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;

GameMap gameMap;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.update();

    gameMap = new GameMapImpl();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

    cam.update();
    gameMap.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    gameMap.render(cam,batch);

}


@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();

}
}
```

TileType.java:

```
package com.mygdx.game.world;

import java.util.HashMap;

public enum TileType{

SHADEDTILE(1,true,"ShadedTile"),
BLACKTILE(2,true,"BlackTile"),
WHITETILE(3,false,"WhiteTile"),
GRIDTILE(4,false,"GridTile"),
SPIKE(5,true,"Spike"),
CLOSEDDOOR(6,true,"ClosedDoor"),
OPENDOOR(7,true,"OpenDoor");


public static final int TILE_SIZE = 32 ;
private int id;
public boolean collideable;
private String name;
public float damage;
private TileType(int id,boolean collidieable, String name){

}
public boolean isCollidable() {
    return collideable;
}
private TileType(int id, boolean collideable, String name,float damage){
    this.id=id;
    this.collideable=collideable;
    this.name=name;
    this.damage=damage;
}


public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public boolean isCollideable(){
    return  collideable;
}
public String getName(){
    return  name;
}
public float getDamage(){
    return  damage;
}
public static HashMap<Integer,TileType>tileMap;
static {
    for (TileType tileType : TileType.values()){
        tileMap.put(tileType.getId(),tileType);
    }
}
public static TileType getTileTypeById(int id) {
    return tileMap.get(id);
}


}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" 
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mygdx.game.world.GameMapImpl.getTileTypeByCoordinate(GameMapImpl.java:74)
at com.mygdx.game.world.GameMap.doesRectCollideWithMap(GameMap.java:49)
at com.mygdx.game.entities.Entity.update(Entity.java:26)
at com.mygdx.game.entities.Player.update(Player.java:25)
at com.mygdx.game.world.GameMapImpl.update(GameMapImpl.java:56)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:40)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mygdx.game.world.TileType.<clinit>(TileType.java:50)
... 8 more
```

Sorry if this isn't the optimal way to show the code, but I'm not sure how else to show whats going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Next time, you might want to read our help regarding [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Narrowing down the example makes it easier for others to help you with it & demonstrates that you've made an effort to understand the problem. Dumping a wall of code & expecting others to sift through it all for the important bits & debug it for you is generally met with disapproval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This means that something wasn't initialized

```
at com.mygdx.game.world.TileType.<clinit>(TileType.java:50)
```

This means that it happened on line 50 on TileType.

You forgot to initialize the tileMap hashmap

Comment: @Shroomius if the answer solved your problem, mark it as correct

Comment: well, now i get these errors `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpriteBatch.begin must be called before draw.
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:512)
 at com.mygdx.game.entities.Player.render(Player.java:36)
 at com.mygdx.game.world.GameMapImpl.render(GameMapImpl.java:44)
 at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:41)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)`

Comment: @Shroom read the first line

Comment: @Shroom - Stack Exchange is not a debugging service. The answer to this question is useful because it shows you how to use the errors you get to help yourself solve the problem. It's a "teach a man to fish" thing.